# tf-idf: am I understanding it right?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, text-processing, information-retrieval, tf-idf

I am interested in doing some document clustering, and right now I am considering using TF-IDF for this.

If I am not wrong, TF-IDF is particularly used for evaluating the relevance of a document **given a query**. If I do not have a particular query, how can I apply tf-idf to clustering?

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly actually: **tf-idf** gives you the **relevance of a term in a given document**.
So you can perfectly use it for your clustering by **computing a proximity** which would be something like

```
proximity(document_i, document_j) = sum(tf_idf(t,i) * tf_idf(t,j))
```

for each term t both in doc i and doc j.

Answer (score 4):

For document clustering. the best approach is to use **k-means algorithm.** If you know how many types of documents you have you know what k is.

To make it work on documents:

a) say choose initial k documents at random.

b) Assign each document to a cluser using the minimum distance for a document with the cluster.

c) After documents are assigned to the cluster make K new documents as cluster by taking the centroid of each cluster.

Now, the question is

a) **How to calculate distance between 2 documents:** Its nothing but cosine similarity of terms of documents with initial cluster. Terms here are nothing but TF-IDF(calculated earlier for each document)

b) **Centroid should be**: sum of TF-IDF of a given term/ no. of documents. Do, this for all the possible terms in a cluster. this will give you another n-dimensional documents.

Hope thats helps!

Comment: can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642930/how-can-i-compute-mtf-idf

Comment: so lets say i have 3 documents like this {1.1, 0, 3.3, 4} {0, 2, 0, 3} {1, 1, 1, 1} and their centroid is being {2.1/3, 3/3, 4.3/3, 8/3} right?

Answer (score 1):

TF-IDF serves a different purpose; unless you intend to reinvent the wheel, you are better of using a tool like [Carrot](http://project.carrot2.org/algorithms.html). Googling for document clustering can give you many algorithms if you wish to implement one on your own.

Comment: how is TF-IDF not related to clustering? how will you cluster text documents?